# Calling the preventDefault method in the compositionend event has no effect

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, contenteditable

```js
var tempNode = document.getElementById('view_1');
tempCNode.addEventListener('compositionend', function(e) {
  console.log(e.cancelable); // true
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div id="view_1" class="view" contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of the input method and not let it display directly in the `div`.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: so you want any forms?

Comment: What's tempCNode?

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem recently.Here is my understanding:

Using 'e.preventDefault() ' in the 'compositionend' event in JavaScript is technically possible, but it may not have the effect you expect. According to a Stack Overflow discussion, calling preventDefault in the compositionend event does not have any effect. This is likely because the compositionend event signifies the end of a composition session, and preventing the default action at this point may not be meaningful as the input composition is already completed.
If you are trying to control or modify the behavior of text input, you might need to use other events like 'input', 'keydown', or 'compositionstart'. However, the specific approach would depend on what you are trying to achieve.